# Update ACF custom fields for new WooCommerce order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to update 2 ACF custom fields every time an order is created.
We have orders coming from our own website and orders coming from an external marketplace integration. My goal is to differentiate the 2 type of orders using custom fields in the order.

The data for the custom fields is provided by an external marketplace integration. The first field has to be filled with the ordernumber (if it it exists) and the other field is just a simple true/false field.

For website orders we're using "Free shipping". For external orders, the provided shipping details are as follows:
[Shipping "Verzending voor bol(xxxxx)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeYcd.png)

I'm trying to get the shipping method using the `woocomerce_new_order` action, and using  `$order->get_shipping_method()`

However, when a new order is created, the custom fields won't update.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'vliegwerk_bolcom_order_filter', 99, 2);

function vliegwerk_bolcom_order_filter( $order_id, $order ) {

   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

   $verzendmethode = $order->get_shipping_method();
   $bol_ordernummer = (int) filter_var($verzendmethode, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 
                    
   if ($bol_ordernummer > 0) {
       update_field('field_61fa977c8dff9', $bol_ordernummer, $order_id );
       update_field('field_61fa95f594b13', 1, $order_id );
   }
```

}

I already tested the `woocommerce_new_order` trigger, it works as expected.

I've also tried updating the fields using a foreach loop, and triggering the function with a shortcode. This also works as expected.

However, when combining it all together, the fields won't update. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For whatever it's worth, `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` you already have the order object passed as the second parameter in the function.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but something you could try...Are you sure the order ID and post ID are the same? I would assume they are not. In that case it may be unlikely the the post ID portion of the ```update_field``` function is incorrect. I believe you can get a post ID from the order object though. So it would look like: ```update_field('field_61fa977c8dff9', $bol_ordernummer, $order->ID);```.